# How to use COUNT result in function without returning it?

Tags: mysql

Say I am trying to get the IDs of duplicates from a table, but I do not want the count. I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) c
FROM wp_posts
GROUP BY post_title, post_type HAVING c > 1;
```

Is it possible to change the query to use the result of count without actually returning it (only return IDs).

I know I could use a nested select statement but is there a better way?

EDIT: I know this is possible but was wandering if there were a more efficient query.

```
 SELECT ID FROM (
  SELECT ID as ID, COUNT(*) c
  FROM wp_posts 
  GROUP BY post_title, post_type HAVING c > 1
) as derived;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the count in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts
GROUP BY post_title, post_type HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: So simple, and obvious (now). Thank you!